# Populate model in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, service, interface, model

I am getting an Object from a service.

```
export class CompanyFormComponent implements OnInit {


@Input() public companyId: string;
  company: Company;
  companyForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private companyService: CompanyService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }
```

Yet I am trying to create new from the service:

```
this.companyService.getSingle(this.companyId).subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.company = data;
        }
);
```

When I console.log data, it shows me the exact object I want to get.
But when I console.log company, it is `undefiend`

What to do?

Comment: Where are you logging the company? Are you sure it happens after the data is received?

Comment: Yes sure, this is the snippet: ```this.companyService.getSingle(this.companyId).subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.company = data;
        }
      );

    console.log(this.company);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen from the comment, you are trying to console.log outside the subscribe function, which gets executed before the service gets its response (Asynch call). Please try below and you should see the value to company object:

```
this.companyService.getSingle(this.companyId).subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.company = data;
          console.log(this.company)
        }
);
```